# Traduire l'expression « foot voting »

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, politique

Comment peut-on traduire l'expression « *vote with their feet* » ou « [*foot voting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_voting) » ?

Les propositions suivantes ne me conviennent guère et restent trop calquées sur l'anglais :

1. faire valoir son opinion en déménageant ;
2. voter avec ses pieds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Voter avec ses pieds* est l'expression consacrée en français, aussi bien pour signifier que des gens ont déménagé par désaccord avec un régime politique, ou se sont abstenus de participer à un vote, ou plus généralement que des gens ont choisi de ne pas participer à quelque chose. C'est en fait plutôt l'expression anglaise qui est un gallicisme au départ, je crois.

Quelques exemples cités sur [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/voter+avec+leurs+pieds.html) :

> … des centaines de milliers de Cubains ont voté avec leurs pied … ([rapport de l'ONU])
>
> Les gens réagissent en "votant avec leurs pieds", en quittant leur région dans l'espoir de trouver de meilleurs revenus. ([Parlement européen](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+CRE+20000117+ITEMS+DOC+XML+V0//FR&language=FR))
>
> vous risquez d'exaspérer les membres de votre groupe, qui décideront peut-être de voter avec leurs pieds ([Nintendo](http://www.nintendo.fr/Jeux/Wii/Major-Minor-s-Majestic-March-281826.html))

Et ailleurs :

> Loi OGM : pourquoi les députés UMP ont voté avec leurs pieds ([Rue 89](http://rue89.nouvelobs.com/2008/05/15/loi-ogm-pourquoi-les-deputes-ump-ont-vote-avec-leurs-pieds))

Comment: Et encore un autre exemple dans la bouche du célèbre démographe Hervé le Bras : *"Ils ont voté avec leurs pieds", remarque Hervé Le Bras, parlant des citoyens qui sont allés chercher leur bonheur en dehors des cités.* [Le Monde du 17.09.2012](http://www.lemonde.fr/culture/article/2012/05/31/le-francais-cet-homo-periurbanus_1710736_3246.html)

Answer (score 1):

*Voter avec ses pieds* est la traduction de l'expression *Foot voting*.

Bien que le sens soit légèrement différent, il est possible que ces expressions proviennent du latin *pedibus ire in sententiam* qui désignait à l'origine une manière de voter où un sénateur en rejoignait un autre pour marquer son accord avec lui.